# How to get search to work on "left-to-right" multi select - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using the [jQuery Multi-Select](http://loudev.com/) to have a "left-to-right" multi select, and I want to add search functionality to this multi select, which is working in the [searchable demo](http://loudev.com/#demos) using [QuickSearch](https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch) library, but I am not able to get this working, and I get no errors.

*I have searched for a more modern solution, since both of the projects are very old, but I have not been able to.*

In the below snippet is an example on what I am trying to do.

```js
$('.searchable').multiSelect({
  selectableHeader: "<input type='text' class='search-input form-control form-control-sm' autocomplete='off' placeholder='Search..'><br>",
  selectionHeader: "<input type='text' class='search-input form-control form-control-sm' autocomplete='off' placeholder='Search..'><br>",
  afterInit: function(ms) {
    var that = this,
      $selectableSearch = that.$selectableUl.prev(),
      $selectionSearch = that.$selectionUl.prev(),
      selectableSearchString = '#' + that.$container.attr('id') + ' .ms-elem-selectable:not(.ms-selected)',
      selectionSearchString = '#' + that.$container.attr('id') + ' .ms-elem-selection.ms-selected';

    that.qs1 = $selectableSearch.quicksearch(selectableSearchString)
      .on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.which === 40) {
          that.$selectableUl.focus();
          return false;
        }
      });

    that.qs2 = $selectionSearch.quicksearch(selectionSearchString)
      .on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 40) {
          that.$selectionUl.focus();
          return false;
        }
      });
  },
  afterSelect: function() {
    this.qs1.cache();
    this.qs2.cache();
  },
  afterDeselect: function() {
    this.qs1.cache();
    this.qs2.cache();
  }
});
```

```css
.ms-container {
  background: transparent url('../img/switch.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

.ms-container:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  clear: both;
  min-height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ms-container .ms-selectable,
.ms-container .ms-selection {
  background: #fff;
  color: #555555;
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
}

.ms-container .ms-selection {
  float: right;
}

.ms-container .ms-list {
  /* -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075); */
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  /* box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075); */
  /* -webkit-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s; */
  -moz-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  border: 1px solid #e4e5ee;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.ms-container .ms-list.ms-focus {
  border-color: rgba(66, 80, 165, 0.02);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  outline: 0;
  outline: thin dotted \9;
}

.ms-container ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.ms-container .ms-optgroup-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.ms-container .ms-optgroup-label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #4b4e68;
}

.ms-container .ms-selectable li.ms-elem-selectable,
.ms-container .ms-selection li.ms-elem-selection {
  border-bottom: 1px #eee solid;
  padding: 13px 13px;
  color: #71748d;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.ms-container .ms-selectable li.ms-hover,
.ms-container .ms-selection li.ms-hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #5969ff;
}

.ms-container .ms-selectable li.disabled,
.ms-container .ms-selection li.disabled {
  background-color: #efeff6;
  color: #c6c6d3;
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://efp.i-r.dk/js/jquery-quicksearch.js"></script>
<script src="https://efp.i-r.dk/js/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>



<select class="searchable" name="Users" id="Users1" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="User1">User1</option>
  <option value="User2">User2</option>
  <option value="User3">User3</option>
  <option value="User4">User4</option>
  <option value="User5">User5</option>
</select>


<select class="searchable" name="Users" id="Users2" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="User1">User1</option>
  <option value="User2">User2</option>
  <option value="User3">User3</option>
  <option value="User4">User4</option>
  <option value="User5">User5</option>
</select>
```

Can any one help find a solution for getting this to work, or maybe point me to a more modern script? .. it is very important for me that the "left-to-right" selection will be done on click of the element, and not clicking on a ekstra button.

Comment: If you try these changes `$selectableSearch = that.$container[0].children[0].children[0],` and `that.qs1 = $($selectableSearch).quicksearch` that should make your search work

Comment: Hi @CarstenLøvboAndersen .. unfortunately that did not make any difference, no search, no error eigther.

Comment: Try look at the demo below in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

I've changed the selector:

```
var that = this,
  $selectableSearch = that.$container[0].children[0].children[0],
  $selectionSearch = that.$container[0].children[1].children[0],
  selectableSearchString = '#' + that.$container.attr('id') + ' .ms-selectable .ms-elem-selectable:not(.ms-selected)',
  selectionSearchString = '#' + that.$container.attr('id') + ' .ms-selection .ms-elem-selection.ms-selected';
that.qs1 = $($selectableSearch).quicksearch(selectableSearchString)
  .on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 40) {
      that.$selectableUl.focus();
      return false;
    }
  });

that.qs2 = $($selectionSearch).quicksearch(selectionSearchString)
  .on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 40) {
      that.$selectionUl.focus();
      return false;
    }
  });
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.searchable').multiSelect({
  selectableHeader: "<input type='text' class='search-input form-control form-control-sm' autocomplete='off' placeholder='Search..'><br>",
  selectionHeader: "<input type='text' class='search-input form-control form-control-sm' autocomplete='off' placeholder='Search..'><br>",
  afterInit: function(ms) {
    var that = this,
      $selectableSearch = that.$container[0].children[0].children[0],
      $selectionSearch = that.$container[0].children[1].children[0],
      selectableSearchString = '#' + that.$container.attr('id') + ' .ms-selectable .ms-elem-selectable:not(.ms-selected)',
      selectionSearchString = '#' + that.$container.attr('id') + ' .ms-selection .ms-elem-selection.ms-selected';
    that.qs1 = $($selectableSearch).quicksearch(selectableSearchString)
      .on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.which === 40) {
          that.$selectableUl.focus();
          return false;
        }
      });

    that.qs2 = $($selectionSearch).quicksearch(selectionSearchString)
      .on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 40) {
          that.$selectionUl.focus();
          return false;
        }
      });
  },
  afterSelect: function() {
    this.qs1.cache();
    this.qs2.cache();
  },
  afterDeselect: function() {
    this.qs1.cache();
    this.qs2.cache();
  }
});
```

```css
.ms-container {
  background: transparent url('../img/switch.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

.ms-container:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  clear: both;
  min-height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ms-container .ms-selectable,
.ms-container .ms-selection {
  background: #fff;
  color: #555555;
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
}

.ms-container .ms-selection {
  float: right;
}

.ms-container .ms-list {
  /* -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075); */
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  /* box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075); */
  /* -webkit-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s; */
  -moz-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  border: 1px solid #e4e5ee;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.ms-container .ms-list.ms-focus {
  border-color: rgba(66, 80, 165, 0.02);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  outline: 0;
  outline: thin dotted \9;
}

.ms-container ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.ms-container .ms-optgroup-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.ms-container .ms-optgroup-label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #4b4e68;
}

.ms-container .ms-selectable li.ms-elem-selectable,
.ms-container .ms-selection li.ms-elem-selection {
  border-bottom: 1px #eee solid;
  padding: 13px 13px;
  color: #71748d;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.ms-container .ms-selectable li.ms-hover,
.ms-container .ms-selection li.ms-hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #5969ff;
}

.ms-container .ms-selectable li.disabled,
.ms-container .ms-selection li.disabled {
  background-color: #efeff6;
  color: #c6c6d3;
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://efp.i-r.dk/js/jquery-quicksearch.js"></script>
<script src="https://efp.i-r.dk/js/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>



<select class="searchable" name="Users" id="Users1" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="User1">User1</option>
  <option value="User2">User2</option>
  <option value="User3">User3</option>
  <option value="User4">User4</option>
  <option value="User5">User5</option>
</select>


<select class="searchable" name="Users" id="Users2" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="User1">User1</option>
  <option value="User2">User2</option>
  <option value="User3">User3</option>
  <option value="User4">User4</option>
  <option value="User5">User5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @CastenLøvboAndersen that fixed the issue .. Thank you very much for your help :-)

Comment: @StigKølbæk No problem happy to help